# How to download custom field file of related post after submit cf7 form

Tags: wordpress-hook

here is my sit link https://snehaclasses.com/download/
here I wants to download pdf of related paper after fill contact form7 which I give in modal.
I am using CPT for post type ('sample-papers') and Custom field for paper name('sample- paper') and for pdf('upload').whats the problem plz help me..
here is my download.php and functions.php code which I used

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>JEE Sample Papers </th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead> 
            <div class="row">
                 <?php
                 wp_reset_postdata();
                  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                  $args =array(
                  'post_type' =>array( 'sample_papers'),
                  'category_name' => 'jee', 
                  'posts_per_page' => -1 
                   );
                  $postslist = get_posts( $args );
                  $i = 0;
                  foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
                  $featuretitle = get_the_title($post->ID);
                  $post_id    = get_the_id();
                  $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );   
                  $i++;
                  ?>

                 <tr>
                    <td> <?php the_field('sample_paper')?></td>
                    <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-stretch" >
                        <div class="modal-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal1<?php echo $i;?>">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <?php
                                $file = get_field('upload');
                                if( $file ): ?>
                                <span data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="card-title view-post" style="cursor: pointer;  position: absulate;right:0 !important;">Download</span> </p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr> 
                    </div>
                <div class="modal modal1<?php echo $i;?>" id="post<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="postModalLabel"><?php the_field('sample_paper') ?></h5>
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                
                                    <?php
                                        if (get_field('form')):
                                            echo get_field('form');
                                        else:
                                            echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="159" title="Contact form 1"]');
                                        endif; 
                                     ?>
                               
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
          
            </div>
        </table>
     </div>
```

in funtions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'example_download' );
function example_download() {
global $post;
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
 $post_id    = get_the_id();
 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function (event) {
        if ('159' == event.detail.contactFormId && $post_id = get_the_id();) {
            window.open('<?php the_field('upload', $post->ID,  $categories);?>',
                '_self');
        }
    }, false);
</script>
<?php
 }
```

Comment: You need to explain what problem you are having.

Comment: I want to auto download custom field 'upload' after submit pop model.